# Separating grid view events and html to reduce reptition

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, separation-of-concerns

I'm fairly new to ASP.NET and programming in general, and one of the problems I'm currently struggling to grasp is reducing repetitive code.

My goal is to have a master page that contains a grid view, then numerous pages can contain the grid. However, I want to be able to share code between my grids but at the same time be able to adapt unique code to each and everyone of them as some will have different attributes and data.

I've looked into separation of concerns, and other various posts/blogs but haven't found a definitive answer to how I can actually achieve what I want.

I've already tried using master pages and it worked quite well until my application continued to expand, plus I'd prefer to only use my master pages for presentation.

Could anyone provide a simple example of how I can achieve this?

***Happy to provide additional information!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending the day doing research and testing numerous possibilities I've pretty much answered my own question.

I've setup a master page that contains the grid, the content page then retrieves the grid using accessors. This grid is then set to a property in the base class which makes it accessible where I need it to be.

*edit*

Event handlers were created to handle the grid events in the content pages, then those methods were overridden to allow the calls to bubble up to the base class thus allowing me to assign unique, page specific and common code where I needed it to be.